# web browser upload screen hides some files in c:\windows\system32

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox

This is very strange

I am in Windows 7

I tried creating an administrative command prompt and creating a file there

called a.a

I did another called aa.exe earlier

```
C:\Windows\System32>copy con a.a
sdf^Z
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\Windows\System32>dir a.a
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B411-D580

 Directory of C:\Windows\System32

06/09/2015  02:07 AM                 3 a.a
               1 File(s)              3 bytes
               0 Dir(s)   4,005,048,320 bytes free

C:\Windows\System32>
```

Then I go to ge.tt and click to bring up the standard upload screen

I have tried this in FF or Chrome, same issue.

[image]

Notice that a.a and aa.exe  aren't showing in the web browser file browsing dialog box, but are in cmd

They show in windows 7 explorer window

And in case it makes any difference, they are not hidden (H attribute is not set)

```
C:\Windows\System32>attrib a.a
A            C:\Windows\System32\a.a

C:\Windows\System32>attrib aa.exe
A            C:\Windows\System32\aa.exe

C:\Windows\System32>
```

So I don't see why my web browsers' file browsing dialog box is hiding them.

Notice that it is selected to show all files. And I tried typing * into the box but still it didn't show those files a.a and aa.exe

Comment: Do you have "protected operating system files" unchecked in Explorer > Tools > Folder Options > View tab?

Comment: @DavidPostill Of course. Any techie would have that silly option unchecked! Of course I have that one unchecked even for about 12 years years, the time since starting using Windows XP!    I have all 3 of those options set well(show, don't hide e.t.c.). And by the way, I said the windows explorer window shows it fine, it is only the file upload window that the web browser brings up that behaves oddly.  And you can see the attributes of the file, only the archive bit is set, not H/S. And if you want to try it for yourself there is nothing stopping you from seeing if you can reproduce the problem

Comment: I may try it later ;)

Comment: Do you know of another upload site to test with? I don't have an account on ge.tt

Comment: @DavidPostill You do not need an account on ge.tt Just hit the giant uploading button that says "drag and drop to upload a file or click ". You don't even need to upload a file there. (And even if you did want to upload a file, you don't need an account to do it). It will be your web browser opening up a dialog box to browse files on your own computer. e.g. c:\windows\system32

Comment: Chrome is currently crashing. I'm doing a reinstall.

Comment: @DavidPostill OK.  Thanks. BTW, as mentioned, FF shows the same behavior as chrome

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28837/discussion-between-davidpostill-and-barlop).